# Как считать информацию из input и записать её в state?

Tags: reactjs

Как в React считать значение из input-а и
записать его в state?

Comment: Что у вас не получается?
Помните, что **учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы
пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста,
отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при 
решении задачи (для этого нажмите [edit]). Например, приведите код,
который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

> Как в React считать значение из input-а и записать его в state?

Вот так такое делается.

```js
//
function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('')
  return <div>
    <input value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={_ => alert('Стейт = ' + val)}>Посмотреть стейт</button>
  </div>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы данные считывались с input-a, но обработчик метода вызывался на кнопке. Как мне записать значение из input-a в state при клике на кнопке, вызвав на ней обработчик, в котором хочу эти данные использовать.

Comment: @Anton, ты можешь сделать из моего примера свой вариант? Так будет понятнее что за кнопка... Что за инпут... И как они расположены относительно друг друга.